# Mathematica Notebook Navigation Shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts, mathematica, mathematica-notebook

I really enjoy structuring Mathematica Notebook with different part & sub-parts, however, I have not yet found the shortcuts to navigate it efficiently.

For example, how can I use keyboard shortcuts to:

- Go from one paragraph to another?
- From one cell to another?
- "Open" or "Expend"?

Comment: What do you mean by parts? Groupings of input/output?

Comment: I guess I mean "Cell" and "Expand" them.

Comment: There's also the [Mathematica mode for Emacs](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4567/), which is completely customizable.

Answer (score 2):

To open and close cell groups you want `Shift+Ctrl+{` and `Shift+Ctrl+}` respectively.

There are heaps of shortcut keys listed in the documentation:
[NotebookShortcuts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NotebookShortcuts.html) 
and
[KeyboardShortcutListing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html)

If you want anything extra, you need to combine the appropriate command or [FrontEndToken](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FrontEndTokens.html) and put it into the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file. This file can be found in

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
              "TextResources", "X", "KeyEventTranslations.tr"}]
```

where you replace `"X"` by the platform you have, either `"X"`, `"Windows"` or `"OSX"`.

For example, a shortcut for moving to the next cell can be implemented by adding

```
Item[KeyEvent["g", Modifiers -> {Control}], 
     FrontEndExecute[SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Cell]]]
```

to the `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.

For more info, here's a SO question on [customizing mathematica shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts) (with good links) and one on [adding a key to (un)comment code in Mathematica 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604837/keyboard-shortcut-to-un-comment-out-code-in-mathematica-7).

Comment: @500: Not a problem. Did you manage to get all of the navigation shortcuts you wanted?

Comment: Not yet, I have to much work :( Actually, may I send you something ? I am having a problem since this morning going absolutely nuts, maybe I am missing something evident to your eyes. I would not know how to address the problem on the forum without posting a huge question. It is essentially about nested Function & Manipulate !

Comment: @500: Sure, you can find my email address on my homepage. I'm meant to be typing up a thesis at the moment, so I can't promise a quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways to do this in Mathematica, other than the arrow keys (which I'm sure you already knew about). I don't know why, but they never seem to have developed a navigational like you can find in many different programs. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, Thank You Soandos. I will leave this unanswered yet in case somebody knows an Hack to that.

Comment: No problem. I don't think there can be though (unless they replace the whole GUI for mathematica, and use the .NET api to do the work behind the scenes, which would be a LOT of work for little gain).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do to skip past cells quickly is to hold Shift and press up/down to highlight the cell(s) you want to skip.  Then let go of Shift and press the same direction to advance to the space just above/below the last highlighted cell.